# Google App Engine CORS “Error parsing ./app.yaml: Unknown url handler type”

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, yaml

I'm trying to apply CORS to one of my app engines, but I'm encountering an error. I've tried looking at the recommendations for other answers (spacing) but it still errors:

app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs10

env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: production
  CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME: domain-name-server:australia-southeast1:db_name

handlers:  
- url: /.*
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://domain_name-fixed.appspot.com/
```

Errors

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [/home/project/domain_name-server/app.yaml]
Unknown url handler type.
<URLMap
    secure=default
    static_files=None
    application_readable=None
    auth_fail_action=redirect
    require_matching_file=None
    static_dir=None
    redirect_http_response_code=None
    http_headers={u'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://domain_name-fixed.appspot.com/'}
    url=/.*
    script=None
    upload=None
    api_endpoint=None
    expiration=None
    position=None
    login=optional
    mime_type=None
    >
  in "/home/project/domain_name-server/app.yaml", line 10, column 73
```

nodejs cors settings

```
let cors = require("cors")

let origin =
    [
        "http://localhost:8080",
        `http://${ip.address()}:8080`,
        "http://localhost:4000",
        `http://${ip.address()}:4000`,
        "https://domain_name-fixed.appspot.com/"
    ]

app.use(cors({
    origin,
    credentials: true
}))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only set HTTP headers for static files. You need to do the CORS part in nodejs code.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. I updated my question to include the cors setting. Maybe I need to use the ip instead of its url address?

Comment: Remove `http_headers` from the above handler. `http_headers` can only be used in `static_files` and `static_dir`. And depends on the env, you might need to use ip or domain. or `*`.