# Can I set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: in gcloud app engine?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cors, gcloud

I have problems with CORS. How to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*"` in app.yaml if I have handling URL? I tried to add this, but it does not work.

Some code in app.yaml:

```
handlers:
# Serve php scripts.
- url: /.*
  script: auto

  # http_headers: 

  #   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
  #   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST"
  #   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type, Authorization"

    # Serve images as static resources.


- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|map|PNG))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|map|PNG)$  
  http_headers: 
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST"
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type, Authorization"
entrypoint :
  serve   handle.php
```

Code in handle:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers Content-Type, Authorization");
header("Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
ini_set('allow_url_fopen',1);
switch (@parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path']) {
    case '/':
        require 'index.php';
        break;
    case '/login':
```

Comment: Does it work without specifying `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST"` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type, Authorization"`?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56414634/google-app-engine-cors-error-parsing-app-yaml-unknown-url-handler-type) i think this is what i want, but how to work in php or gcloud? they say  depends on the env, i dont know how to do that. and thank @FaridShumbar to answer my question but it not work.

Comment: As per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref), the wildcard should be working. Perhaps you need to try the `*` without quotes, i. e. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. Does it work?